# All day upgrading from 14.10 to 15.04?

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, time

It seems really strange. I have started my upgrade process in the morning, after more than 12 hours it is still installing the upgrades?
Is it normal or something went wrong?

Comment: Cancel the update and check your internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

There's [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1447600) where the installer hangs instead of formatting the partition in some cases.  I ran into it doing a "Something Else" install, but managed to press on by starting over with an "Upgrade" install.

If you provide more info, someone may be able to tell if this is your situation.

Comment: Sometimes its waiting for user input. If you do a command line install, you'll see the request for user input, but the GUI AFAIK never prompts you.